# What does this "value:06b" mean?

Tags: python, string-formatting

I found a code where this was written

```
def int_to_bin_converter(value):
    return f"{value:06b}"
```

And I don't understand what the `value:06b` does.

Comment: It's this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec